# Downloading the information of a queryable WMS with QGIS

Tags: qgis, geoserver, wms

I've produced a WMS queryable layer using GeoServer. Accessing it through a QGIS connection, it lets me retrieve the information of a particular point using a GetFeatureInfo request. In fact, it gives me the option of seeing that information in 3 formats: HTML, Spatial Object or Text:

[image]

Now I wonder if there's a way to download that information as a file of any kind or the only option is to copy-paste it.

Comment: A WMS service returns a **picture** of the data you can not reliably extract meaningful information from it - if you require actual data you must use a WFS or WCS endpoint to fetch actual data.

Comment: Well, that's not correct @Ian_Turton. In fact, if the WMS layer is queryable, a GetFeatureInfo request (as the one pictured in my post above) returns the information corresponding to the selected point (https://www.ogc.org/standards/wms/introduction)

Comment: sure you can get (some) information for a point from some layers but that is not the way to access the data in any meaningful way.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve or why. But I'll give it a try. As you tagged it with *geoserver* I assume that you're looking for something else than doing it from the QGis interface.

Yes, you can download it as a file. Use *curl* or similar and call the WMS server using the same URL that QGis called to get that information. It is however a bit impractical as GetFeatureInfo requires a coordinate for the object to query. It is probably not easier than copy paste from QGis unless you always know where your object is.

If you are looking for a way to extract the data from the server to a JSON file, the easiest way would be querying the WFS endpoint of *GeoServer* instead and specify GeoJSON format.

For instance:
http://localhost:8088/geoserver/sf/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=sf%3Aroads&outputFormat=application%2Fjson

would give you all features of the sf:roads layer. In addition you can add a CQL filter to extract only features of interest.

Comment: Actually, I need it from QGIS. I tagged the question also as GeoServer just in case something could be configured in the server to facilitate or allow the process.

Comment: Never heard of such functionality in QGIS: my guess is that you'll have to write your own QGIS plugin to achieve that.